# If $ f(x)dx+g(y)dy=0$ then why this doesn't imply $f(x)=g(y)=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, self-learning

For functions $f(x)$ of $x$ and $g(y)$ of $y$, where $x,y$ are independent, why cannot we conclude from the expression
$$ f(x)dx+g(y)dy=0\tag{1}$$
that $$f(x)=g(y)=0$$

If the original equation was $$ f(x)+g(y)=0\tag{2}$$ then we can say each function must be zero separately, otherwise a change in $x$ for a constant $y$ cannot always lead to (2)

But why is this not true for (1)?

Comment: You're second claim isn't true. For example if $f(x)=-1$ for all $x$ and $g(y)=1$ for all $y$.

Comment: @AlanAbraham Ah yes, in general, all one can say is that f(x)=-g(x) =c, where c is a constant and thus f(x)dx=-g(y)dy=k. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: If the context is that you're trying to solve a differential equation, then $f(x)dx + g(y)dy = 0$ is in general going to give you a solution in the form of a *curve* where $dx$ and $dy$ are not independent -- and also $f(x) + g(y) = 0$ does not imply $f, g$ constant.